# How to detect that I am reading from a file when write is not completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, concurrency, java-io

We have a multithread program which does the following:

`thread_1` is a listener of hard disk to detect a new file created.  We use `WatchService` api in Java 7. When a new file is created by another program, `thread_1` detects and get it and put it to a `PriorityBlockingQueue` ex:

```
priorityBlockingQueue.add(FileObject)
```

`FileObjComparator` is a custom object implement comparator.  It is sorted by created time and `fileCreatedTime` field in `FileObject` I get from system time when detect this file:

```
 public int compare(FileObject o1, FileObject o2) {
        return o1.getFileCreatedTime().compareTo(o2.getFileCreatedTime());
    }
```

`priorityBlockingQueue` is initializes as:

```
DataFileQueue.priorityBlockingQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<FileObject>(100000, new FileObjComparator());
```

and `Thread_2` will process this next to the last file in this `priorityBlockingQueue`

```
if(priorityBlockingQueue.size) > 1)
   process(priorityBlockingQueue.poll());
```

2 threads are running in parallel but when I process a number of large files, sometime `Thread_2` process a **file while it is being written**.  I detect this because recheck the content file and the result of processing.

This program is running on Centos 6.2, this hard disk partition is mounted in async mode.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: "sometime Thread_2 process a **file is writing** i detect this because recheck the content file and the result of processing." is not very clear. You detect that Thread2 is writing to a file when it should not?

Comment: i promise that this file is created by one (and only one another program), and when file is created there is no modification on it :( :(

Comment: @tubcvt Please look at my more detailed answer.

Comment: What is the other program that is writing the files?

Comment: this is 3rd third party program , and i can not change it 's code.

Comment: @tubcvt I know that the 3rd program is creating and writing the files one by one !! Please look at my edited answer at the bottom "step by step".

Answer (score 2):

If you really are processing the 2nd to last file then I'm surprised that the size of it is growing unless multiple processes or threads are generating the input files.  Make sure that the other process that is creating the files flush and close each file *before* writing the next one.

- You could read the file in blocks and then go back over a period of time to see if any additional data was added to the file and process it at that time using a `RandomAccessFile`.  If you are reading a file line by line you would need to do your own pagination unfortunately.  If the file is line based then you should make sure that the line termination characters close the file.
- Another thing you can try is to delay the processing of the file a bit to let the file system flush its buffers.  Ugly and unreliable but maybe necessary.
- If you can adjust the output process then you could end the file with a magic string and then not process the file until the magic string is seen.
- You could have the process the writes the file, write the size of the file into a separate file with a ".size" extension (or something).  The size file would help you verify that you are reading the correct number of characters.
- Another thing to try is to `Runtime.exec("/bin/sync");` before you start reading from a file to synchronize the file system if you are running on ~unix system.  The problem is that support for this is highly OS dependent.  It also can be a real performance killer.  He's the man page on my Mac:

  > The sync utility can be called to ensure that all disk writes have been completed

Comment: thanks for helping me , But i can not adjust the output process :( :(. do you have any better ideal :(, i try processing the only 5th file, and keep 4 old file , but sometime this strange still occur, (about 2 file in 200 k file ) :( :( .

Comment: I added another idea to try to call `/bin/sync` before you start reading from a file.

Comment: When atempting anythig like this, I have the file-producer write the file as '/tempFiles/SomeData.TMP', close it, then rename/move it to '/realFiles/SomeData.dat'.  It appears, fully written and flushed, in the folder where it is going to be picked up, (and signal an inter-process named semaphore).

Comment: @MartinJames : this will not work. A third party program will not take care of this :'/tempFiles/SomeData.TMP.

Comment: @Gray do you mean this ? The sync utility can be called to ensure that all disk writes have been completed before the processor
     is halted in a way not suitably done by shutdown(8).  Generally, it is preferable to use shutdown(8) to
     shut down the system, as they may perform additional actions such as resynchronizing the hardware clock
     and flushing internal caches before performing a final sync.

Comment: Yes @moskito-x, it is often used before shutdown but `sync` will force the write buffers to be cleared.  I think it is worth a try.

Comment: @Gray : That does not explain how to find, if the write to a file is closed. (maybe it takes about 14 minutes to finish). How many times will you run the sync utility ? And the "the sync utility" will give you a file list of important files ready to pass to thread_2 ? The created files are known by thread_1 but not the ready to process files for thread_2 !

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying @moskito-x.  His problem is that the 2nd to last file still has IO buffered somewhere.  By calling `sync`, the OS buffers may be flushed to disk.  He already knows the names of the files.

Comment: No. His problem is that he pass a file to Thread_2 at the create time. This may work for very small files but if a large file takes about 1 minute or more to finish. thread_2 will process it a the incomming time not at the finshed time.

Comment: You are incorrect @moskito-x.  Thread_1 is a file listener that adds files to a prioritized list that have been created by another process.  Thread_2 processes the "next to the last file".  The problem is that even though the thing that creates the files is done with the file and starts the next one, the next to last file is still growing.

Comment: Thread_1 is **only a listener** and it takes no care if the the file created by another process is ready/finished to pass to thread_2 !!

Comment: That's correct.  That's why @moskito-x he processes not the last file in the list (which is still being written to) but the 2nd to last file.  The assumption is that the process that is generating the files has closed the previous file when it is writing the next one.  He's probably processing logs or something.

Comment: @Gray At the create time of a file I did not care about the prioritized list. I would put only files to that list that are really finished. At the create time really no file is complete and should not appear in the prioritized list. Or thread_2 takes care that the files in the prioritized list are really ready to read.

Comment: Sigh.  It's an _external_ program that is writing the files @moskito-x.  It's not a different thread it's a different _program_ that he doesn't have control of.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using semaphores to organize access to each file, so as no file will get
written onto by more than one thread at a time. I think each file object should have its
own semaphore, and each thread should try to acquire the semaphore before writing to the
file.

Comment: i don't think so in this my situation, because  this file is created by one (and only one another program), and when file is created there is no modification on it. Only thread_2 read it, and process with it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Your Comparator should order by last modified time, not creation time. I don't see how you can know for example that two files opened in ordr A, B will be completely written in the same order, unless you positively know for a fact that file production is strictly sequential. You haven't said so.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT** a more detailed answer.

The problem is ...

**You wrote**:

**It is sorted by created time and fileCreatedTime field in FileObject I get from system time when detect this file:**
....

**thread_1 is a listener** of hard disk to detect a new file created. We use WatchService api in Java 7. When a new file **is created by another program**. ...  **thread_1 detects and get it** and **put it to a PriorityBlockingQueue ex**:

- The create time and the "file writing finished time", can be very different. (depending on the file size).

**for example:**

Open a File manager. Start downloading a about 60 mb File. Note the Create time. After about 3 minutes look at the final time.

to detect a new file, looking at the create time is the **wrong moment** to "**put it to a PriorityBlockingQueue ex**:"

thraed_1 have to wait until the file writing has **finished**. And then he can put it to "**a PriorityBlockingQueue ex**:"

**How can I detect that the write is completed on a file ?**

3 not too complicated options

- a.) Compare the file is created and the file is ready time.
  **or**
- b.) Observe that the size of the file is growing steadily. If the
  file is finished it stops growing.
  **or**
- c.) Try to move it to a temp folder.

**What would you prefer ?**

I would prefer solution c.

A file opened for writing can not be moved. After the **3rd party program** closes the file it can be moved.

**The necessary steps.**

- thread_1 is watching for created files by a **3rd party program**.
- thread_1 trying to move it to a xyztmp folder ( every 10 or 20 or ... seconds).
- thread_1 looking for new incoming files in the 
  xyztmp folder and put it to a PriorityBlockingQueue ex.

---

**solution b. is more complicated.**

thread_1 put the incoming filenames and the size in a control array to compare 3-5 times.(every 5 seconds or more).

Array

```
(filenamexyz.dat, size1, size2, size3, ...).
(filenameabc.dat, size1, size2, size3, ...).
(filenamefgh.dat, size1, size2, size3, ...).
....
```

If a file identified by name every 5 comparative sizes are the same the **3rd party program** has finished writing to this file.

Now it can be put to a PriorityBlockingQueue ex:

**Let's look step by step**

We assume thread_2 started when the list.size is 2 !

- 3rd party program starts writing files one by one.
- 3rd party program starts writing FILE_1.
- thread_1 detects created FILE_1, put it in the list.
- 3rd party program finished writing FILE_1.
- 3rd party program starts writing FILE_2.
- thread_1 detects created FILE_2, put it in the list.
- if(priorityBlockingQueue.size) > 1) TRUE
- thread_2 starts with reading and processing first file in the list FILE_1.

---

- 3rd party program finished writing FILE_2.
- 3rd party program starts writing FILE_3.
- thread_1 detects created FILE_3, put it in the list.
- thread_2 finshed processing FILE_1.
- thread_2 starts with next file in the list FILE_2.

---

- 3rd party program finished writing FILE_3.
- 3rd party program starts writing FILE_4.
- thread_1 detects created FILE_4, put it in the list.
- thread_2 finshed processing FILE_2.
- thread_2 starts with next file in the list FILE_3.

  NOW THE TROUBLE STARTS

---

- 3rd party program finished writing FILE_4.
- 3rd party program starts writing FILE_5. (FILE_5 Larger then FILE_4).
- thread_1 detects created FILE_5, put it in the list.
- thread_2 finshed processing FILE_3.
- thread_2 starts with next file in the list FILE_4.
- **thread_2 finshed processing FILE_4.**
- **thread_2 starts with next file in the list FILE_5.**
- **thread_2 finshed processing FILE_5.**
- 3rd party program finished writing FILE_5.

If the file that the 3rd party program writes **is larger and needs more time** to write and thread_2 has finished reading the smaller FILE_4 .

thread_2 takes the next file out of the list - FILE_5, whether the file is ready to read or not.

FILE_5 is the file 3rd party program still writes.
FILE_5 is the file thread_2 is reading and processing. The bytes thread_2 **reads are only** the bytes **3rd party program has written** at this time.

Comment: please read deep in my question!! I read 5th file only, i think we don't need to track size of the file because the program write this file only create file one by one :( :(

Comment: what should "read the 5th file only" mean? You wrote "but when I process a **number of large files**". There is more then one. 2.) if you check every second, whether the size changes. Then it is not necessary to pass the file to the thread_2 as long as the size increases.

Comment: i have a files queue, (this queue sorted by file created time), and when i have n file in queue , I process last (n-5) file only.

Comment: You can not pass a file to thread_2 while writing to this file is not completed !!!!!!!!! YOU HAVE TO CHECK THIS in thread_1. YOU WROTE "**sometime Thread_2 process a file while it is being written. I detect this because recheck the content file and the result of processing.**"

Comment: He has no control over the writing dude.  He is only detecting files that appear in a directory written by something else.  Thread_1 is the file detector _not_ the writer.  Thread_2 is the reader of the file.

Comment: THAT'S WHAT I TALKING ABOUT. The problem is that thread_1 put all files to the prioritized list at the moment he detect a file. Whether they are ready or not.

Comment: moskito-x please read my question carefully :(. 3rd party program write file one by one (mean a file is must completed then another file  is started to written), and i sorted my queue by timestamp when the file is create (not completed), and i only only only read the file which older than this file. Please understand my question ! thanks for helping me